# Android NotificationListenerService#onNotificationRemoved(..., int reason) not called by System

Tags: java, android

Based on the Documentation on the Android Developer site, the   [onNotificationRemoved(with reason)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#onNotificationRemoved(android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification,%20android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService.RankingMap,%20int)) method allows one to get the reason why a notification was dismissed e.g. user cleared all notifications, or just your notification etc.

I have tested some of the other callbacks i.e. [onNotificationPosted](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#onNotificationPosted(android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification)) and [onNotificationRemoved without reason](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#onNotificationRemoved(android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification)) and they are successfully called.

Below is the implementation of the NotificationListenerService I created:

```
package com.solo.notificationlistener;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService;
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification;
import android.util.Log;


public class MyNotificationListenerService extends NotificationListenerService {

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);

    if (sbn.getPackageName().equals(getBaseContext().getPackageName())) {
        Notification notification = sbn.getNotification();
        String notificationText = notification.extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT);
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                String.format("Just posted notification: %s", notificationText));
    }
}

@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    super.onNotificationRemoved(sbn);

    if (sbn.getPackageName().equals(getBaseContext().getPackageName())) {
        Notification notification = sbn.getNotification();
        String notificationText = notification.extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT);

        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                String.format("Dismissed notification: %s", notificationText));
    }
}

@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn, RankingMap rankingMap, int reason) {
    super.onNotificationRemoved(sbn, rankingMap, reason);
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Dismissing with a reason");

    if (sbn.getPackageName().equals(getBaseContext().getPackageName())) {
        Notification notification = sbn.getNotification();
        String notificationText = notification.extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT);
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                String.format("Dismissed notification: %s\n Reason: %s",
                        notificationText,
                        (reason == NotificationListenerService.REASON_CANCEL) ?
                                "Specifically cancelled my app" :
                                "Cancelled all perhaps"
                ));
    }
}
```

}

Any ideas on why this behaviour occurs?
Any assistance is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

OnNotificationRemoved with reason is for API >= 26
Could it be for that reason the method is not trigerring ?